# Как сделать чтобы не вылетала ошибка http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Как сделать чтобы можно было создавать таблицы в одинаковыми названиями?

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
login = request.form.get('login')
password = request.form.get('password')
password2 = request.form.get('password2')
surname = request.form.get('surname')

if request.method == "POST":
    if not (login or password or surname or password2):
        flash("Заполните всё")
    elif password != password2:
        flash("Пароли не равны")
    else:
        hash_pwd = generate_password_hash(password)
        new_user = User(login=login,surname=surname,password=hash_pwd)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('login.html')
```

Вот такая ошибка

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (sqlite3.DatabaseError) database disk image is malformed
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (login, surname, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Семен', 'Бажанов', 'pbkdf2:sha256:150000$Bpjtjn6U$17d72fd99a43175e425d178cd2a3530998f8935d92c7c84074feb3e7b1cf72e0')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)
```

Comment: И как вы будете различать две таблицы, если у них будут одинаковые имена?

Comment: Ну у них есть id, а он всегда разный

Comment: У меня в базе данных есть id,name, surname,password. И допустим у двух людей одинаковые имена и фамилии. И мне надо чтобы было это возможно

Comment: Вам не нужно создавать несколько таблиц с одним именем, вам нужно создать одну таблицу, и добавлять строки (записи) в нее.

Comment: Я добавил код, как его надо изменить?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ошибку, которая возникает

Comment: Ошибка означает, что у вас на какой-то колонке (или на всех) стоит ограничение уникальности (UNIQUE constraint), т.е. в колонке не может быть двух одинаковых значений. Нужно смотреть вашу модель User.

Comment: Да, я увидел там было  unique=True, но теперь вылезает другая ошибка

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (sqlite3.DatabaseError) database disk image is malformed
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (login, surname, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Семен', 'Бажанов', 'pbkdf2:sha256:150000$Bpjtjn6U$17d72fd99a43175e425d178cd2a3530998f8935d92c7c84074feb3e7b1cf72e0')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)

Comment: database disk image is malformed - значит что база битая. В вашем случае проще базу заново создать.

Comment: Все спасибо теперь все работает